# gcc assembler unable to determine architecture

Tags: gcc, assembly, architecture, configuration

I have gcc installed, however as (the assembler) is not working correctly. I get the following error

```
gcc tmp.c
fatal error: as: unknown host architecture (can't determine which assembler to run)
```

I get the same error when I run as. I think its something to do with the configuration of gcc, but I am not certain. (My cpu is an intel core 2, so the --with-arch32=i686 might be an issue)

Some possible useful information

```
$ gcc -dumpmachine
x86_64-linux-gnu

$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9' `--with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu`


Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9)


$ uname -mpio
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help would be greatly apprectiated. :)

Comment: Try reinstalling `binutils`, or maybe try to compile with `-march=cpu-type`. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html

Comment: Are you trying to compile a 32-bit build on a 64-bit machine? You might need multiarch libraries.

Comment: Reinstalling binutils worked. Thanks for the help!