# g++: as fails to determine which assembler to run

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, g++, binutils

Today I wanted to recompile one of my projects. Compiling this project had already worked on my machine, but this time an error occured.

The compiler output goes:

```
fatal error: as: unknown host architecture (can't determine which assembler to run)`
```

for the line:

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../../.vscode -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I../../.vscode -I. -o Main.o ../../Main.cpp
```

I tried to compile some other projects, but realized, that I wouldn't be able to compile anything using any c++ compiler, so I looked it up.

The only fitting thread I found was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785554/gcc-assembler-unable-to-determine-architecture) but the solution 'reinstalling binutils' didn't work for me (tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall binutils` as well as `--reinstall gcc`, `g++` and `build-essential`)

One possible reason for this problem that comes to my mind is the iOS-toolchain I installed yesterday - I had to install some different clang versions - but I actually didn't change anything on the system's assembler...

If someone's got an idea; any help would be appreciated :)

---

### Additional info:

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit

AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor × 6

---

```
uname -m
```

returns `x86_64`

---

```
 gcc -march=native -v -E - 2>&1 <<<'' | grep "cc1" | egrep -o -e $'-m(arch|tune)=[^ "\']+'
```

returns `-march=bdver2` and `-mtune=bdver2`

---

already tried `gcc [...] -march` with `bdver2` and other architectures

---

`g++ -v -c HelloWorld.cpp` gives me: http://pastebin.com/Ks2be0hL

---

`type -a as` says:

```
as is /usr/local/bin/as
as is /usr/bin/as
```

---

`as --version` sadly just show's me the error again, but `info as` tells me it's `binutils-2.26.1-system` from 2016-08-07

---

`dpkg -S /usr/bin/as` prints: `binutils: /usr/bin/as`

Comment: Try using `g++ -v -c hello.cpp` to see what sub-commands the top-level g++ driver program runs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i'll give it a try :) (rhime)

Comment: To clarify: have you tried to compile a simple Hello World executable?

Comment: Yes, just did that now, but same error again :/
`int main()
{
    return 0;
}`

Comment: @PeterCordes Here's the `g++ -v -c HelloWorld.cpp` output: http://pastebin.com/Ks2be0hL

Comment: [Edit] it into your question.  And also the output of `type -a as`, and `as --version`.  Maybe also `dpkg -S /usr/bin/as` to see which package provided that `as`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type -a as` says `as` is `/usr/local/bin/as`.  This is what gcc is running, not `/usr/bin/as`, because `/usr/local/bin/as` is found first in your `$PATH` search order.  This is why re-installing packages and so on is having no effect: something else you installed (probably manually) installed a non-standard `as`.

Have a look at `/usr/local/bin/as` and figure out where it came from, and what to do with it.  For now you can just rename it to `as.unknown` or something, and then everything will use the normal system assembler (`/usr/bin/as`).

Comment: Ah, i see. Thank you, i'll try it :)

Comment: Great, compiling the HelloWorld.cpp now works. :) But for the two QT-applications i've tested it for, there's now a new error. I'll edit it in.

Comment: @Leso_KN: If it's a different error, then it's a different question and you should post it separately instead of changing the question and invalidating this answer.

Comment: oh, ok! Well then: closed :)

Comment: Found the solution anyways; i was able to solve it with just the same trick (`which ld` gave me one result, but i renamed it anyways - seems like there _was_ another ld, that's why i was confused first). But thanks all again, thread closed :)

Comment: @Leso_KN: `which` only shows the first hit, like the `type` shell builtin without `-a`.  But ok, that does sound like it was part of the same problem after all.  I should have said "if it's a different kind of error", or something, since an edit about /usr/local/bin/ld being a problem would have been ok.  (but of course the answer doesn't really change, as you figured out :)

Comment: Ah ok, i didn't know that ;) Yes, in the end it was kind of the same error _and_ (moreover) it indeed _was_ related to that iOS-sdk thing (search for `ld: unknown option: -plugin` - only osx issues xD

Comment: @Leso_KN: `which` has a man page which documents its options.  `which -a` would have worked.  But you should prefer the `type` shell built-in for most uses because it shows you aliases and shell functions as well as searching `$PATH`.

Comment: ok, i'll use that method in the future. Thank you for your help again :)

Comment: I just had the same exact problem with `as` and `ld`. maybe it is related somehow to Ubuntu (incorrect default package?..).

Comment: @interDist: I'm pretty sure no packages distributed as an official part of Ubuntu install anything in /usr/local/.  So no, not a "default" package, but possibly some third-party package that installed a version of `as`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `binutils` and reinstall it using the following steps:

Create an installation directory `/opt/cross`, and make sure you have write permission to  .

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/cross
sudo chown user /opt/cross
export PATH=/opt/cross/bin:$PATH
```

Download and install

```
wget http://mirrors.muzzy.it/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.9.tar.gz
tar xvf binutils-2.9.tar.gz
cd binutils-2.9
linux32 ./configure --prefix=/opt/cross --target=aarch64-linux --disable-multilib
```

If dosn't work remove `--target=aarch64-linux`, the `--disable-multilib` option means that we only want our Binutils installation to work with programs and libraries using the aarch64 instruction set, and not any related instruction sets such as aarch32, run:

```
linux32 ./configure --prefix=/opt/cross --disable-multilib
linux32 make
linux32 make install
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I already thought of that, but just to make sure: you really want me to `apt-get purge binutils`? Because it would look like [this](http://hubit.selfhost.eu:9812/LsoftProducts/laCaja/fl/%C3%96ffentlich/Purging%20binutils.png)... This is really not meant saccastic, i'm just not sure if i should do this :/ (also note the `ubuntu-desktop*` near the end..)

Comment: Run `apt-get remove` without `purge`, `purge` will remove all dependencies