# Simple c program will not compile in linux, gets strange error

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc

My compiler is pooched.  I'm trying to compile a simple "Hello World" program in c and I get this error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-    F/System/Library/Frameworks/'
ld: unknown option: -plugin
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Googling the error kept giving me links to help for MAC OS.  My computer is running Ubuntu 16.04.

This came about from [having this error before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879672/g-as-fails-to-determine-which-assembler-to-run) and implementing its solution or installing clang and removing usr/local/bin/as.  Compiler still won't compile butthe error is now the aforementioned.

The program I'm trying to compile:

```
/* Hello World program */

#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

}
```

The uname -m commands brings back x86_64.  Running as -version brings back:

```
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `x86_64-linux-gnu'.
```

For what it was worth I was trying to compile a python program for iOS.  Before trying that the compiler worked.  What do I need to do to fix the compiler?

Comment: "For what it was worth I was trying to compile a python program" - Python is an interpreter language, not compiler. Not clear what you mean. See [ask].

Comment: Read the error
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-    F/System/Library/Frameworks/'
ld: unknown option: -plugin
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

ld doesn't know option -plugin. Take a look at the command that link the objects

Answer (score 0):

Read the error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '- F/System/Library/Frameworks/' ld: unknown option: -plugin collect2: error: 
ld returned 1 exit status ld doesn't know option -plugin.
```

Take a look at the command that link the objects. And also the directory maybe does not exists.